# REGEXP_LIKE - Find pattern containing special character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to find if a column value contains the following pattern:

```
513-2400-23 - Valid
513-PBS-231 - Valid
521-PB-21 - Valid
52-12-21 - Valid
513-2321 - Not Valid
```

I have tried the following version and many other but they are working for one case but not for other.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('B12-23-43', '.-.-.') THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N' END FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: is `B12-$23-43` valid ?

Comment: No special characters except hyphen are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Case WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('B12-23-43', 
              '^[[:alnum:]]{1,}-[[:alnum:]]{1,}-[[:alnum:]]{1,}$') THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N' END 
FROM DUAL;
```

**UPDATE**

To also cover cases such as this one: `544-445-PBBTS-24.3`, it could be extended as shown below:

```
Select Case When 
   Regexp_Like('B12-23-43', 
   '^([[:alnum:]]{1,}-){2}[[:alnum:]]{1,}(-[[:alnum:]]{1,}\.[[:alnum:]]{1,})?$') 
   THEN 'Y'
   ELSE 'N' END 
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I have missed one more use case..where there is a chance of '544-445-PBBTS-24.3'. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: decimal at all positions possible ?

Comment: Looks like SQL Regex is not as simple as Java. Decimal is possible only at end of line always.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that valid pattern requires exactly two dashes, this should work:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('B12-23-43', '^[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+$') THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N' END FROM DUAL;
```

The pattern requires the string to start in one or more non-dashes, then to have a dash, then some more non-dash characters, and finally some more non-dash characters.

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22574)

Comment: Works, but also allows `B12-23*-43` .. isn't it ? I mean like, it allows all characters in between!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar You are right, it does. However, so does the OP's solution, though, because he uses the take-all `'.'` dot pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN (LEN('B12-23-43') - LEN(REPLACE('B12-23-43', '-', '')) = 2) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N' END FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This solution allows two dashes to be together, as in `513--2321`. This may or may not be valid - OP does not provide an example to say one way or the other.

Comment: sorry, did not see such cases.